# How can I change how VS Code indent multi-line comments?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc, tslint, auto-indent

When I auto re-indent my code in VS Code, multi-line comments are indented with the asterisks not vertically aligned. I would like them to be aligned so that I can comply with [`jsdoc-format`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/jsdoc-format/).

How can I force it to align the asterisks vertically?

Here is an illustration:

```
/**
* How VSCode indents it
*/

/**
 * How I want it
 */
```

Comment: If you create those comments via "/**" and tab complete  the comments are in jsdoc format.  Are you saying that vscode reformats your previously compliant jsdoc-style comments?  [I see that it does?....]

Comment: @Mark yes it does