# Multi-line comment indentation formatting in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, formatting, comments, multiline

In Visual Studio 2019, are there any settings to allow the configuration of the multi-line comments in order to always align new star characters (i.e.`*`)?

When inputting the first new line in a multi-line comment, a star (i.e. `*`) character is automatically generated and aligned with the backslash (i.e. `\`) character and not with the first star (i.e. `*`) character:
[image]

It is really annoying to always have to manually fix this indentation issue. I have tried looking at the "Text Editor" formatting settings, however, there doesn't appear to be any settings for configuring multi-line comments. I also have been unsuccessfully searching around to see if there is an obvious fix.

Does anyone know how to make Visual Studio auto-align the star characters (i.e. `*`) in multi-line comments with the proceeding star characters?

Comment: Dup (that doesn't have an answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54137002/how-can-i-change-how-vs-code-indent-multi-line-comments

Comment: @Eljay That question is specific to Visual Studio (VS) Code. My question was targeting Visual Studio 2019. Extensions made for VS Code are **not** compatible with Visual Studio and vice versa. My question is **not** a duplicate of that question. My solution is not applicable for VS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. @VRichardJP was exactly right - this formatting feature is for a Visual Studio extension to do. After trying a few, I found an extension that does exactly what I need and allows some flexibility: [Doxygen Comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FinnGegenmantel.doxygenComments).

I am actually using Doxygen, so this extension is perfect for me, but even if you aren't, it still is really useful. The configuration is super straight forward and flexible (shown in the below picture). The extension options allow you to modify how the comments will look when auto-completed.
[image]

With this extension, the auto-indentation works perfectly now:
[image]

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT StackOverflow requires that I wait 48 hours before I could accept my own answer. I got pre-occurpied with other things, but I was planning to come back to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to use an extension for this feature.
For example [Auto Comment Blocks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kevinkyang.auto-comment-blocks) seems to do the job.

Comment: This extension is for Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio. I also saw this too, but it only installs for Visual Studio Code. This extension doesn't work sadly. But, I think you are right with requiring an extension to do it for me :/